# is there a way to corrupt a single page in the pdf file so I can still open it

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I have a use case to get pdf samples that are corrupted, but should open. Typically if you print the document, it should fail at page 30.

1. I am trying to make one pdf file corrupted and combining with a non corrupted file, but adobe cannot do it as the file that is corrupted is cannot be combined.
2. when I corrupt only last page of the pdf, the entire pdf won't open

Comment: tried this, but the pdf still renders if I change EOF and gives invalid if I change header

Comment: *"if you print the document, it should fail at page 30."* - you cannot guarantee that. Some viewers may recognize the corruption early and fail early.